# Incomplete extraction of Zip files using Python

Tags: python, zip

I have a script where I download a bunch of Zip files (150+) from a website and unzip them. I just noticed that the Zip files weren't completely extracting - i.e., there should be 68 files in each directory and there are only 62. The script ran fine with no errors.

Any thoughts? I tried running one Zip file through by itself and it extracted fine. Could the operation be timing out or something? Please forgive my code, I'm new.

I'm running Python 2.7.

```
import csv, urllib, urllib2, zipfile
from datetime import date

dlList =[]
dloadUrlBase = r"https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/DSD/Download/Cache/SSA/"
dloadLocBase = r"Z:/Shared/Corporate/Library/GIS_DATA/Soils/"
stateDirList =[]
countyDirList =[]
fileNameList=[]
unzipList =[]
extractLocList=[]
logfile = 'log_{}.txt'.format(date.today())
with open(r'N:\Shared\Service Areas\Geographic Information Systems\Tools and Scripts\Soil_Downloads\FinalListforDownloads.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    stateDirList.append(row['StateDir'])
    countyDirList.append(row['CountyDir'])
    fileNameList.append(row['File_Name'])
for state, county, fileName in zip(stateDirList, countyDirList, fileNameList):
    dloadDir = dloadLocBase + state + r"/" + county + "/" + fileName
    requestURL = dloadUrlBase + fileName
    extractLocList.append(dloadLocBase + state + r"/" + county + "/")
    try:
        urllib.urlretrieve(requestURL, dloadDir)
        print requestURL + " found"
        urllib.urlcleanup()
        unzipList.append(dloadDir)
        f = open(logfile, 'a+')
        f.write(dloadDir + " has been downloaded")
        f.close()
    except:
        pass
for zFile, uzDir in zip(unzipList, extractLocList):
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(zFile, "r")
    zip_ref.extractall(uzDir)
    zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: can you share a zip file to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/DSD/Download/Cache/SSA/wss_SSA_PA001_soildb_PA_2003_[2017-10-03].zip    Like I said, the files extract fine one at a time using the zip module. but when I did them in the batch sequence only most of the archive was extracted.

Comment: I don't see any difference between platform archiver and Python zipfile. What exactly doesn't work with the file?

Comment: in the zip file there is a folder named 'tabular' with 68 txt files (tables).  When i ran my script, the 'tabular' folder only had 62 txt files.  I manually extracted the zip file again(with python and windows) and got 68. so its not the download, its occuring during the unzip process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a syncing issue with my network. We use a cloud based network that syncs with our offices, so somehow not all of the files were being synced and getting left in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just passing when an error is raised, log / print what the error is. That should indicate what is the issue or a set of issues.

except Exception as e:
    print e # or print e.message

Comment: I agree my error handling is pathetic at best. the problems arent coming from that part of the script, everything is downloading fine, something is happening during extraction

Comment: [traceback,print_exc()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) is a useful shortcut for printing exceptions.